# Is it correct to use @embedded with this data class

Tags: android, android-room

Is it bad to use the Room data class tag @Embedded in following case? Or would it be more correct to use one-to-many relations?
Basically you can have many customers and each customer has a reseller, the same reseller can be the reseller of many different customers of course.

```
@Entity(tableName = "customer")
data class CustomerEntity(
    @ColumnInfo(name = "Customer_id") @PrimaryKey override val id: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "Customer_name1") override val name1: String,
    ...
    @Embedded val reseller: CustomerResellerEntity?,
)

@Entity(tableName = "resellerCustomer")
data class CustomerResellerEntity(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) val customerResellerId: Long = 0,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "Reseller_name1") val name1: String?,
    ...
)
```

The endpoint: GET /api/standard/v1/customers

```
[CustomerDto{
  id    integer($int32)
  name1 string nullable: true
  ...
    CustomerResellerDto{
      name1 string nullable: true
    ...
    }
}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `@embedded` in the `CustomerEntity` is just a way to group columns from the `customer` table into an object; it assumes the `CustomerResellerEntity`'s columns are actually in the `customer` table.

Your concept is ok, but you need to create an additional non-entity class. You can have that class embed the `CustomerEntity` and `CustomerResellerEntity`.

See https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/relationships#one-to-one, where it demonstrates a `UserAndLibrary` class that's similar to what you're looking for.

You'd write something like (untested)

```kotlin
// Copyright 2023 Google LLC.
// SPDX-License-Identifier: Apache-2.0

// NOTE - NOT AN @Entity
data class CustomerAndReseller(
    @Embedded val customer: CustomerEntity,
    @Relation(
         parentColumn = "resellerId",        // in CustomerEntity
         entityColumn = "customerResellerId" // in CustomerResellerEntity
    )
    val reseller: CustomerResellerEntity
)
```

and you call it from the DAO:

```kotlin
// Copyright 2023 Google LLC.
// SPDX-License-Identifier: Apache-2.0

@Transaction // make sure you have this; @Relation adds a query!
@Query("SELECT * FROM CustomerEntity")
fun getCustomersAndResellers(): List<CustomerAndReseller>
```

Comment: Thanks, what would be the advantage of this approach over the other one?

Comment: Also you linked a one-to-one relationship, in my case I see a one-to-many relationship because one reseller can have multiple customers, right?

Comment: The one you posted won't work unless the CustomerResellerEntity fields are in the customer table.

As for one-to-many, because you're coming from the "many" side, the @Relation is fetching the one CustomerResellerEntity for that CustomerEntity. If you were fetching CustomerResellerEntities, you'd need to have a list of CustomerEntities.

Comment: "won't work unless the CustomerResellerEntity fields are in the customer table" but that's what you achieve using the @Embedded tag

Comment: Those fields are stored in the `resellerCustomer` table, aren't they?

Comment: I think that I actually don't need the Entity tag over resellerCustomer, the fields are stored in the customer table, that's what embedded do.

Comment: If the reseller fields are stored in `customer`, you don't have a one-to-many relationship; you have copies of the same reseller in every customer. In that case, it'll work to have the `@Embedded` in `CustomerEntity`, but your database isn't normalized. I'd recommend normalizing the database first, then using the approach I suggested.